# D-Link DNS-320 Degraded RAID-1 will not rebuild...? any suggestions?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, raid-1

I'm not sure what caused it but it just keeps looping the rebuild process.
Gets to 100% of re-syncing and then starts at 0% again...

Just interested in a solution but not finding anything with D-Link.
The only reference to reproduced problem... 
More details available:
http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=50417.0

UPDATE:
I decided to pull the drive and wipe it clean in another PC.
Removed all partitions on that machine, put it back in the NAS.
Now it won't let me check the "Reconfigure to RAID1" box... :-/

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You need fun_plug. When installed, log on to the NAS with telnet and rebuild via `mdadm`:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md1 --> see removed disk
```

If the new disk is the right disk, then:

```
mdadm --manage --add /dev/md1 /dev/sda2
```

Or, if it is the left disk:

```
mdadm --manage --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdb2
```

This launches rebuild. To see the progress:

```
cat /proc/mdstats
```

When finished, edit `/var/www/xml/used_volume_info.xml` and change:

```
<raid_status>2</raid_status>
```

into

```
<raid_status>0</raid_status>
```

Then delete `/var/www/xml/unused_volume_info.xml`.

Then it will be OK in the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rebuild until you format the new drive.
Pull out your 'good' drive. Put in the new drive, and format it.
Then put your good drive back. You should see the 'degraded' status but now be able to rebuild.
BUT, don't expect it to work. There is a bug with the DNS 320 firmaware that causes rebuilds to fail. (Google dns 320 won't rebuild).